# RS485 in point-to-point communication

Tags: linux, ppp, rs485

I'd like to achieve TCP over RS485 in point-to-point communication. Due to the hardware, I cannot use RS232. I don't have any equipment yet so I cannot not test anything.

In Linux, can I use slattach process with e.g SLIP protocol to transmit and receive data between two nodes or will that work only with RS232? I know that RS485 is half duplex and I should implement e.g. master-slave protocol on top of that to prevent collisions.

Comment: RS485 doesn't have to be half duplex. If you have the right hardware you can drive it full duplex. I'm not sure about slattach or SLIP but I expect that it's hardware agnostic as long as you have drivers. It was used for communication over acoustic modem in ye olden dayes so I'd be surprised if it was tied to a particular type of hardware.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. I'm forced to drive the system in half duplex. I was also thinking that as long as there is driver support for RS485, it doesn't matter which type of serial line there is under the hood if the file descriptor is obtained always the same way (e.g. /dev/ttyS0 or so).